# Do two solution with same score limit have score order?

Tags: discussion, code-challenge

There was problem asking to write n programs a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n-1</sub>, so that running a<sub>k</sub> outputs a<sub>(k+1) mod n</sub>, and the score is sum(len(a<sub>i</sub>))/n<sup>2</sup>. Lower score the better.

Lots of answers just have a format and with the format score can go as near as you want zero. Do they have order in this case?

Some cases that probably worth discuss:

1. 1/n 2/n
2. 1/n 2<sup>-n</sup>
3. 1/n 0

Comment: Can you post a link to the challenge you are describing?

Comment: It appears that you're really unable to write clear English? ... It takes me a few read to understand the question.

Comment: @user202729 I think it's "unable to judge if it's clear English"

Comment: @user202729 I understand the frustration, but please [be nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). "you're really unable to write clear English" is downright rude and not constructive in any way. Not everyone was raised in an English-speaking environment, myself included. Instead of simply pointing out someone's poor English, you could ask clarifying questions.

Comment: @JungHwanMin ... I don't think that this is rude, just "point out a fact". The OP themselves also say that occasionally.

Comment: @user202729 Perhaps you didn't intend to make it sound like that, but at least to me, it does sound a bit rude. There are alternative ways to "point out a fact" than to state it directly (which is often rude). E.g. "Your English is broken" vs "I am having trouble understanding your English." The latter is more indirect and sincere.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Ok thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If two or more answers have the same score, the default tiebreaker is time - the first answer to reach that score wins. Note that this includes edits - if answer A is edited before answer B is posted, and they have the same score after the edit, answer A wins.

Comment: If one has lower limit of `x` while another is exactly `x`, do they have order?

Comment: @l4m2 I don't understand your question. Answers have concrete-valued scores, not theoretical score functions.

Comment: I *think*, I'm really not sure but I think, this question is about challenges where answerers have come up with methods for getting arbitrarily good scores.

Comment: It might be worth noting that challenge authors may come up with their own tiebreakers.

Comment: @Shaggy I did - "default"

Comment: @Mego requiring `Answers have concrete-valued scores,` is only making meaningless "speaking larger number"

Comment: @l4m2 In the challenge that you are asking about, the score appears to be `lim [n -> inf] Σ|a_i|/n²`. If multiple solutions have the same value for that limit (0), then a tiebreaker is used (either one specified in the challenge, or the default tiebreaker of first-past-the-post). The scores are concrete values here, which is a necessity on this site - otherwise, answers wouldn't be comparable, and there wouldn't be an objective winning criterion.

Comment: I later asked what if one answer has limit while another has exactly the value

Comment: @l4m2 Limits and values are not comparable, so if there was a situation where one answer's score was a limit and another answer's score had a value, there would be no way to decide which is more optimal, so the challenge would lack an objective winning criterion and therefore be off-topic by our rules.

Comment: @l4m2 You can have a scoring method that scores by the asymptotic score, but it needs to be challenge-specific.

Comment: Sometimes when making a question the author doesn't know asymptotic score will appear, so there should be a default